How to effectively access nested JSON objects in Ansible
I have a JSON structure mentioned below and i am not sure how to traverse lower down in the hierarchy:
"json": {
    "count": 5,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "action": "pass",
            "application_groups": [],
            "applications": [],
           "created": "2024-06-20T09:53:20.139779+02:00",
            "custom_fields": {},
            "description": "",
            "destination_address_groups": [],
            "destination_addresses": [],
            "destination_service_groups": [],
            "destination_services": [
                {
                    "created": "2024-06-18T02:00:00+02:00",
                    "custom_fields": {},
                    "description": "",
                    "display": "ICMP (ICMP)",
                    "id": "c52f9be9-b4ca-4dd4-8993-2615c2fe004f",
                    "ip_protocol": "ICMP",
                    "last_updated": "2024-06-18T10:52:44.698368+02:00",
                    "name": "ICMP",
                    "natural_slug": "icmp__icmp_c52f",

I manage to get to the "secondary level" but not "lower" than for example destination_services in the example above. Not sure this is the right way, could anyone suggest a better / working method, please?
The dot approach mentioned / tried below does not work. I guess this has something to do with a mix of lists, arrays and dictionaries?
- name: API CALL (Nautobot GET rules)
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://{{ nautobot_ip }}/api/plugins/firewall/policy-rule/?depth=4
    method: GET
    validate_certs: false
    headers:
      Authorization: Token {{ nautobot_token }}
  register: firewall_rules

- name: SET FACT (Firewall policy rules)
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    firewall_policy_rules: "{{ firewall_rules['json']['results'] | json_query('[].{ dst_services: destination_services, dst_services_names: destination_services.names } ') }}"


My goal here is to create complete mapping (dictionary) of all firewall rules that could be used in further tasks. I hope my question makes sense. I also have some objects that have even more children than destination_services mentioned above.
EDIT:
I would like to get something like:
    "ansible_facts": {
        "firewall_policy_rules": [
            {
                "destination_services": [
                    {
                        "created": "2024-06-18T02:00:00+02:00",
                        "custom_fields": {},
                        "description": "",
                        "display": "ICMP (ICMP)",
                        "id": "c52f9be9-b4ca-4dd4-8993-2615c2fe004f",
                        "ip_protocol": "ICMP",
                        "last_updated": "2024-06-18T10:52:44.698368+02:00",
                        "name": "ICMP",
                        "natural_slug": "icmp__icmp_c52f"
                    }
                ],
                "dst_services_names": "ICMP"
            }
        ]
    },

meaning i would like to able to access both destination services in whole but also their individual attributes like name in the example above ....

What is the expected result? Make it [mre].

Given the simplified mre data for testing
    firewall_rules:
      json:
        count: 2
        results:
        - action: pass
          created: '2024-06-20T09:53:20'
          destination_services:
          - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: A}
          - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: B}
        - action: deny
          created: '2024-06-20T09:53:20'
          destination_services:
          - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: C}
          - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: D}


The below query

  fpr_query: '[].{key: action, value: destination_services}'
  fpr: "{{ firewall_rules.json.results | json_query(fpr_query) }}"

gives
  fpr:
    - key: pass
      value:
      - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: A}
      - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: B}
    - key: deny
      value:
      - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: C}
      - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: D}


You can convert it to a dictionary

 fpr | items2dict:
    deny:
    - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: C}
    - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: D}
    pass:
    - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: A}
    - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: B}


Or, you can create the dictionary right away

  fpr_query: '[].[action, destination_services]'
  fpr: "{{ dict(firewall_rules.json.results | json_query(fpr_query)) }}"

gives the same dictionary
  fpr:
    deny:
    - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: C}
    - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: D}
    pass:
    - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: A}
    - {created: '2024-06-18T02:00:00', id: B}


Hi Vladimir, thanks a lot for your suggestion / solution! I will experiment a bit more and eventually elaborate more, will let you know.

In your example query, do you know how to access only attribute id? Something like fpr_query: '[].{key: action, value: destination_services.id}' ?

What should be the expected result? What is preventing you from putting this into your question?

I am sorry for not being clear enough, i have now modified my original question. I hope this is the way to go.

The working solution (so far) is:
- name: SET FACT (Firewall policy rules)
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    firewall_policy_rules: "{{ firewall_rules['json']['results'] | json_query('[].{ dst_services: destination_services, dst_services_names: destination_services[*].names } ') }}"

It might not be the cleanest one but at least it does what I want.
